# jar file created by Eclipse doesn't run

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed the last version of Eclipse on my pc running on Windows 10.
Every time I try to export the simplest Java project in a runnable jar file, the jar file doesn't work.

Example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Try {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some message", "title!!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

File> Export> Java > Runnable Jar File
All names/ Folders been set OK
Package required libraries into generated JAR (but I tried every other switch )> Finish
The jar file is created but doesn't make anything at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: As suggested by CodePenguin: Run the jar file on the command line to see if there are any errors: `java -jar thefile.jar`

Comment: Can you clarify what you  mean by "doesn't make anything at all". Do you get an error?

Comment: 1 million Thanks DontKnowMuchBut Getting Better !!

When running the jar file on the command line, the message "UnsupportedClassVersionError" appears explaining that the project has been compiled with a more recent version of Jave Runtime (class file version 58.0) while this (which?) version of the Java Runtime only recognises class file version up to 55.0

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Success!! I changed the Compiler compliance level, to 11 (from Properties> Java Compiler) and all went well!! Once again: THANKS to "DontKnowMuchBut Getting Better"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your issue, but your jar needs to contain a manifest file to indicate which class within the jar is the application's entry point. So it may be worth checking whether Eclipse is adding that correctly. Looks like some manual steps may be [involved](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/doc/5bf81818-3805-44c6-af50-2e223ad27870.htm#CreateManifest). The file (META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) should contain contents such as:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_112 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: MyClass
```

For reference, some guidance on adding the manifest (outside of Eclipse) can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

FYI, if you do end up adding a manifest manually, be sure to follow this advice from that page to *add a new line* at the end of the file. Missing it, as I have, can lead to much frustration:

***Warning: The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or carriage return.***

You would create a file, say `Manifest.txt`, containing this (plus a "new line"):

```
Main-Class: Try
```

Then create the jar:

```
jar cfm anyname.jar Manifest.txt Try.class
```

And then run the jar by double clicking it or by running this:

```
java -jar anyname.jar
```

Comment: The Eclipse export wizard will create a _manifest_ for you. The wizard has a "main class" field where you enter the fully qualified class name of the class containing a `main()` method.